# wp_set_post_terms is not updating the count column in term_taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

```
wp_set_post_terms($post_ID, 'my_term', 'my_taxonomy');
```

My problem is that in wp_term_taxonomy, the count is 0 but running that line of code should be making it 1.

I have also added to the register_taxonomy:

```
'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count'
```

If I manually change the count to 1 then my other functionality displays so everything is being done correctly apart from the count column always being 0.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: can you post the full script? are you trying to update term for exissting post or insert a post with and set its term?

Comment: Full code would be helpful here. Are you possibly setting the post term **after** you've queried the post? You may need to requery the post after setting the term. `global $wp_query; $wp_query = new WP_Query($wp_query->query_vars);` should do it. I would also remove the custom callback for update_count_callback unless you need it, as it adds more points of failure.

Comment: what version of wordpress are you using?

Answer (score 6):

if it's custom taxonomy for attachment, you should add to the register_taxonomy :

```
'update_count_callback' => '_update_generic_term_count'
```

Answer (score 2):

Are they drafts, if they are in draft mode they won't be in the count.

Comment: This is what I need. Thanks a lot!